# Sceneview Lags when using Arrays

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm getting a strange behavior here - when i create a simple C# script which holds an Array of classes, where both, the script class and the array classes, are marked as Serializable, my sceneview starts lagging on moving the mouse (when the gameobject, which contains the script component is selected). Also, the lag increases, when the array class has more members, which are marked as SerializeField.

If i add the attribute [field: NonSerialized] over my array, the lag is gone. Also, [HideInInspector] doesn't change a thing - it looks to me like something is causing unity to serialize the script content every frame - which would be a little bit strange, because what should cause such a behavior?

Does somebody know a solution for this?

[Edit: Code Snippet]

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class TestObject{
    public int              IndexX;
    public int              IndexY;
    public int              LengthX;
    public int              LengthY;
    public float            AnimationLength;
    public bool             Animate;
    public float            AnimationSpeed;



    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject      mGameObject;

}


[Serializable]
public class TestScript{

  [HideInInspector]
  public TestObject[] Objects       = new TestObject[256*64];

  void Start(){

  }

  void Update(){

  }

}
```

This very short and basic script causes lagging issues... but an array of 256x64 should not be that hard to serialize.
I'm building a Jump'n'Run game - and i would be very happy to get messages like "OnSerialize" and "OnDeserialize", so i could save and reload my tiles in a simplier format, unity saves the tiles gameobjecs, its meshes an stuff - but thats a heavy overload.. tried to make something like this, with two lists and listening for the "awake" message - but if i get the message in the editor, i can not delete the existing gameobjects - it would be nice, if i could delete and recreate them, when the editor reloads the data.

Comment: Can you post that part of the script? Maybe something can be found in there. Also, are you sure that (serialized) objects aren't touched in any `Update` function?

Comment: Done. And, yes, i'm shure that i don't mark any of my objects as dirty =/

Answer (score 1):

256*64 = 16384 objects.
to avoid dropping frames you'd need to have each one serialize in under 0.002ms (1/30/16384) which is a tall order...

can you avoid the need to serialise in the game thread? can you spawn a thread to do the serialisation asynchronously? that way you can continue to respond to the user...

Comment: No, cause unity decides when and what to serialize, i have no control about it. And its only an assumption, that the serializing causes this behavior. I know, that it might take 1, 2, maybe even 5 seconds to serialize an even bigger array - but that wouldn't be that bad, if the serialization only happens when i want it to or the editor switches to the game view and back on.Maybe it's because unity checks each frame/editor update,if something in my array has changed?Maybe i should use another data structure, with less null values..but then i have to use dictionaries or have to search for a tile

Comment: Maybe an other solution is to serialize it all into a local array, and then read and build it from the local array while playing?

Comment: "If i add the attribute [field: NonSerialized] over my array, the lag is gone"  well its clearly something to do with the serialisation process.....  why not override the Onserialise method and log with a timer how long the process is taken - then you can find out how often unity is forcing it to happen

Comment: @GreyCloud: Wher should i find the OnSerialize Method? Can't find it.. would be great if "MonoBehaviour" would have such a mehod - plus, OnDeSerialize or so, so one can serialize easier data and the reload everything from scratch o_o